# How to replace a character having { special character using a perl command

Tags: html, linux, perl, variables, special-characters

I am using below perl command & but the value is not populating into my html file w.r.t. to it .

commands used :

```
perl -l -p -i -e "s/BER_IMC_SRE_{10}/$BER_IMC_SRE_10/g" $tmpfile501
perl -l -p -i -e "s/BER_IMC_DB_Lat_SRE_{10}/$BER_IMC_DB_Lat_SRE_10/g" $tmpfile501
```

execution logs :

- `perl -l -p -i -e 's/BER_IMC_SRE_{10}/10228/g' /data/scripts/reports/20230629125556374622858//24949_rep.html`
- `perl -l -p -i -e 's/BER_IMC_DB_Lat_SRE_{10}/9/g' /data/scripts/reports/20230629125556374622858//24949_rep.html`

HTML O/P :

[image]

I want to replace the variable BER_IMC_DB_Lat_SRE_{10} with value 9 as shown in the execution logs .

- `perl -l -p -i -e 's/BER_IMC_SRE_{10}/10228/g' /data/scripts/reports/20230629125556374622858//24949_rep.html`
- `perl -l -p -i -e 's/BER_IMC_DB_Lat_SRE_{10}/9/g' /data/scripts/reports/20230629125556374622858//24949_rep.html`

Comment: Did you try to escape the curly braces `{` and `}` ? Should the `$` in front of `BER` be included in the result? If so, you should escape that too

Answer (score 1):

Curly brackets are special in regexes. Escape them:

```
perl -l -p -i -e "s/BER_IMC_SRE_\{10\}/$BER_IMC_SRE_10/g"
```

You can also use the `\Q` to let [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) escape everything for you:

```
perl -l -p -i -e "s/\QBER_IMC_SRE_{10}/$BER_IMC_SRE_10/g"
```

Note that it can still fail if the replacement contains a `/`. It's better to use Perl variables rather than shell variables.

```
r=$BER_IMC_SRE_10 perl -l -p -i -e 's/\QBER_IMC_SRE_{10}/$ENV{r}/g'
```